# Tensorflow object detection evaluation loss

Tags: tensorflow

I'm interested in running the validation images and getting the loss (similar to the one during training) on the validation dataset in Tensorflow's object detection library.

I'm trying to modify _extract_prediction_tensors function in evaluator.py (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/evaluator.py#L38) as follows. I'm adding a loss dict to the tensor_dict so that loss gets evaluated.

```
groundtruth_boxes_list = 
[input_dict[fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_boxes]]
label_id_offset = 1
groundtruth_classes_list = 
tf.cast(input_dict[fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_classes],
                  tf.int32)
groundtruth_classes_list -= label_id_offset
groundtruth_classes_list = 
[ops.padded_one_hot_encoding(indices=groundtruth_classes_list,
                    depth=model.num_classes, left_pad=0)]
model.provide_groundtruth(groundtruth_boxes_list, 
groundtruth_classes_list)          
losses_dict = model.loss(prediction_dict)    
tensor_dict['loss'] = losses_dict
```

But the classification loss that I'm getting is wrong even though I can see that it has classified properly. Not sure if there is still an error in the implementation.

Comment: could you change your class labels to start at 0 by 1-hot encoding the labels?

Comment: Actually, just ignoring even the second runtime warning also works. I was able to see the outputs on Tensorboard.
What I'm interested is to see the" total loss" similar to the one in training on the validation dataset. I want to know how to get this.

Comment: I'm confused. If the RuntimeWarning is unrelated to your question, you should remove that part and update your question to be more clear. I don't know what you're even asking; Are you saying you don't know how to compute loss on a validation set?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question.
For the object detection library provided by Tensorflow, I am not sure how to compute validation loss. On Tensorboard it provides mAP but I also want to know the loss.

Comment: Please upload your MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and explain what you tried, and in what way what you tried didn't solve your problem

Comment: Did this ever get answered? We would like this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The loss is already computed by the evaluation script. I'm currently extracting it with few lines of code. The way to do it is to modify the file "/models/research/object_detection/eval_util.py". In repeated_checkpoint_run() at the line:

```
  write_metrics(metrics, global_step, summary_dir)
```

Here "metrics" is a dictionary with all the class APs as well as all the losses. To extract them add these new lines (indented as the previous line):

```
  for k,v in iter(metrics.items()):
    if 'mAP' in k:
      mAP = v
    elif 'localization_loss' in k:
      loc_loss = v
    elif 'classification_loss' in k:
      cls_loss = v

  print('-> mAP:{} loc_loss:{} cls_loss:{} tot_loss {}'.format(mAP,loc_loss,cls_loss,loc_loss + cls_loss))
```

These values should be the mAP, localization and classification loss of the evaluation data that you set in the config file.